# ASP.NET Security Exception on StringTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, stringtemplate

I use StringTemplate library (http://www.stringtemplate.org/) on my ASP.NET 3.5 web site, and it works perfect on localhost,

I wrote simple code:

```
StringTemplate template = new StringTemplate();
```

but when I try run this on shared hosting, it throws an error:

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

How can I resolve that problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a security problem with shared hosting... [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839300/en-us) will give an idea on what is involved and how to possibly solve this issue...

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But all described there I can't do on shared hosting server...

Comment: @ihorko then the only solution I can think of are to use a different library (which is compatible with "partial trust/shared hosting") or to use non-shared hosting (which supports full trust)...